# Replace DataTable, DataSet with List

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am working on this application since Net 1.1. and it is using all these year - 3 tiers, presentation, business and data.

Data tier is mostly using DataSets and DataTables to get data from SQL, and in order to get more transparent coding I want to use more of strong typed lists.

I was thinking of leaving data tier intact and use business tier to structure data retrieved from data tier. Basically I want to declare new classes and return strong typed lists.

It this a good way to go, do I need data tier anymore (in order to get data from sql to datatable and then convert it to List again) or there is a better way to pull data directly into list in business tier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to pull data into a business tier is to use an ORM like:
[Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) or
[NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/).
or micro ORM like
[Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) or
[Dapper.net](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).

If you're not going to use them, then you will still need to have DAL object and then populate your BO in BLL.

Comment: Using an ORM is great advice. Writing the plumbing logic is error-prone, time consuming code. Also, check out PetaPoco...